# Is there a way to digitally sign only macros (in Excel, Word etc files) with PowerShell?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I want to digitally sign the macros that are in Office document without sign all the file with PowerShell, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Probably this helps: [Programmatically sign a macro - Macro signing automation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c40e3e33-e552-426c-a0f6-add7f484479c/programmatically-sign-a-macro-macro-signing-automation?forum=isvvba)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately there is no answer.

Comment: Yes, that's because you only can automatically add a signature for the document. But you cannot automatically sign code. That would actually kinda defeat the whole point of the digital certificate. So only Excel can sign Excel's VBA code (the file needs to be opened).

Comment: I thought there is a solution like : create an object Excel.Application, load the excel file, extract the macro, sign it, affect it back and save the file.